# Leyning on Chol Ha-moed Sukkot

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, ashkenazi, sukkot, chol-hamoed

Can anyone explain the rationale for the Ashkenazi leyning in chutz la-aretz on Chol Ha-Moed?  For example, on the first day of chol ha-moed, we leyn as follows:  first aliya - uvayom ha sheni; second aliya - uvayom ha-shlishi; third aliya - uvayom ha-revi'i; forth liaya - uveyaom ha-sheni and uvayom ha-shlishi.  The problem:  because of sfeika de-yoma it might be the second day or the third day, but it certainly is not the fourth day, so the third aliya does not seem to make any sense.  As proof for this, on hoshana rabba, we don't have an aliya that includes the eighth day, because that is shimini atseret!  If the concern is not repeating, that doesn't seem to hold up either because in Eretz Yisrael, we just leyn the same day four times.  Is there an explanation in the rishonim or achronim for this order of leyning?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%92

Comment: There are other opinions in the Rishonim. Some have 2-3-2-3, and some have 2-3-3-23, and some have 2-3-2-23 for first day CHM (instead of what you presented 2-3-4-23).

Comment: Steve, Mo'adim Lesimcha, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing this interesting question here! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: AA, after I asked my question, I looked it up in the Abudraham (111), who indeed says it is 2/3/3/2+3 on the first day of CHM.  But I am not aware of any Ashkenazi machzorim that actually have that order, nor any shuls that have that leyning.   So it would be interesting to see which rishonim justify reading 4 in the third aliya - which is the really problematic one.

Comment: Note that _Chabad_ does in Israel similarly to the practice you cite for outside of Israel: it reads (on day 2 of _Sukos_) 2, 3, 4, and 2. (The final _aliya_ is the "_s'feka d'yoma_" _aliya_, but of course in Israel there's no _safek_.)

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to ask the same thing.

Comment: This isn't just the Ashkenazi minhag in chutz la-aretz, it's the Ashkenazni minhag everywhere.